# Is it possible to set the "Min" value in the vertical scale of a candle chart to the value of a call?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a box chart generated dynamically from a drop down and want the `min` value on the vertical axis to automatically be the `MIN()` value of the dataset.

Is it possible to use a formula as the Min value for this field?

[image]

When trying to use a formula it doesn't seem to work

[image]

When leaving it to its default value, the scale is inappropriate for my real dataset

[image]

Comment: I understand what you are looking to do, by any chance you can provide a minimum reproducible sample that can show case the factors you are looking, and the community can have a better grasp of your question.Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Unfotunately, the v-axis only supports numbers as their value. Does Google Apps Script, fall within your accepted workarounds for this? Please let me know so I can post an answer for this workaround. Please do share what are the instances that this values change is it every time a chart is created or when the values are edited?

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, if you are willing to tolerate some dead space after the last candlestick in your chart, place the formula `=min(Data!A:A) in the 'Low' column of the row underneath the data for the last candlestick. You are effectively creating an additional invisible candlestick with no name, whose low point is the dataset minimum so the rest of the candlesticks are scaled accordingly.